# Downloading images via wget

Tags: linux, download, wget, image-processing

When downloading an image with wget using `wget link` I get the following errors:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location:  [following]
--2015-05-24 14:47:46--  http://stripovionline.com/AlanFord/0002_Suplji_zub/1.jpeg
Reusing existing connection to stripovionline.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location:  [following]
--2015-05-24 14:47:47--  http://stripovionline.com/AlanFord/0002_Suplji_zub/1.jpeg
Reusing existing connection to stripovionline.com:80.
```

And after 20 times it terminates with message `20 redirections exceeded.`

I can normally visit the link and download the image manually though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't download that image with my browser either getting "The page isn't redirecting properly" error, so this may as well be a correct `wget` behavior. I suggest you try to download some other image to confirm. For example `http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/sprites.svg` opens fine for me.

If you need to download a file which is only accessible from a particular page, like `http://stripovionline.com/index.html`, you'll need to pass that URL to wget as a referer:

```
wget --referer="http://stripovionline.com/index.html" "http://stripovionline.com/AlanFord/0002_Suplji_zub/1.jpeg"
```

Comment: Your link works fine. It seems that it's their website's behaviour since they don't allow direct links. When I manage to get to the image, I can save it manually.